# React Typescript: render array of strings to an unordered list

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a pure functional component using typescript how do we render an array of strings into an unordered list?

```
import React from 'react';

const Drinks: React.FC = () => {
   const myArray = ['Water', 'Orange Juice', 'Milk'];

  return (    
    <ul>
     <li>Water<li/>
     <li>Orange Juice<li/>
     <li>Milk<li/>
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Drinks };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

const Drinks: React.FC = () => {
  const myArray = ['Water', 'Orange Juice', 'Milk'];

  return (    
    <ul>
      { myArray.map( (drink,index) => (<li key={index} >{drink}</li>)) }
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Drinks };
```

Comment: Sorry, but the type annotations are redundant in the code you posted, you added a type annotation for an error that is not in your code just because the OP complained about an unrelated error. This does not seem right to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` as the children:

```
const Drinks: React.FC = () => {
  const myArray = ['Water', 'Orange Juice', 'Milk'];

  return (    
    <ul>
     {myArray.map(o => <li key={o}>{o}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Drinks };
```

[play](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-arwfwg)

**Note** `key = {o}` is necessary to help react uniquely identify an element for updates. This assumes strings are unique in the array.

Comment: You forgot to give it a key

Comment: I get the error 'Parameter 'o' implicitly has an 'any' type.' then if I change it to `any` I get the error `Cannot find name 'o'.`

Comment: @Bill not sure what the problem in your code is, but the stackblitz shows that the type of `o` is `string` as expected. This should be inferred based on the type of `myArray` which in this case in inferred from the initialization. If `myArray` is typed as `any`  you might get this error, but this is not realted to the question or the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

const Drinks: React.FC = () => {
   const myArray = ['Water', 'Orange Juice', 'Milk'];

  return (    
    <ul>
     {myArray.map((item:string, index:number)=><li key={index}>{item}</li>)} 
     /* using index number as key is not recommendable. 
        But in this case, it doesn't matter.*/ 
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Drinks };
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use map for rendering array like

```
<ul> 
    {myArray.map((arr,i) => 
     return <li key={i}>{arr}</li>
    ) 
</ul>
```

- if directly myArray is unable to access then try this.myArray